# How can I convert Mono<List<something>> to List<something> into reactive programming spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc

I have the following code this returns a Mono<List> and I need a List

```
var test = repo.findAll().collectList().map( a-> {
                return a;
            });
```

spring.boot.version 2.7.0

Comment: Could you explain why you need a list? Blocking outside of tests means that your code becomes synchronous, so why not use a Flux<T> instead? I'm quite sure the repo would return this in a findAll. A Flux can even be returned by the Controller without ever needing Lists. Otherwise if you don't leverage reactive programming practices, you could always use non-reactive libraries.

Comment: As @thinkgruen says, better check why you need directly the list if you are using reactive programming

Comment: My question is how can I use this information in my code? When I do this findall I need to use the information that I have in my database to map and save some information that I receive from another API.

Comment: By save you mean that you write something back to the database? That is also done reactively by R2DBC. when you call the API, you can leverage the reactive WebClient and to process it, Mono and Flux come with a map operation that you can use to work with whatever they are holding once it is ready. You can see that a lot of the concepts are taken from functional programming, so If you are comfortable with Streams and lambdas, reactive programming becomes much easier imo.

Answer (score 1):

If `repo.findAll().collectList().map( a-> {return a;})` returns a `Mono<List<T>>`, you can simply add `.block()` on the end to get back a `List<T>`

```
var test = repo.findAll().collectList().map( a-> {
             return a;
           }).block();
```

`test` will now just be a `List`

Your other option is to `subscribe` to it and pass in a `Consumer` that consumes the List.  `subscribe` is a non-blocking operation.  If you want to `subscribe`, you need to pass in a `Consumer`.

Consider this method, that takes a `List<String>` (making the assumption that you get a list of `String`, it can be a List of anything).

```
public void consume(List<String> strings) {

}
```

if that method is defined in the same class that your call is, you can simply do

```
repo.findAll().collectList().map( a-> { return a;}).subscribe(this::consume);
```

and it will pass the `List<String>` into your method when it's available.

Comment: How can I implement this call with a subscribe method? Can you give an example with subscribe ?

Comment: @ErickGonzalez See my edits